# How to prove that the supremum of this set is 0?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

it sounds like a silly question, but I'm having trouble to prove that

$$
\sup\left(\left\{\left. \frac1n-1 \right|n \text{ is odd}\right\}\right)=0
$$

I'm stuck in proving that
$$
\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists a\in \left\{\left. \frac1n-1 \right|n \text{ is odd}\right\}  a>0-\varepsilon
$$

thanks in advance

Comment: $a=0$ works.${}$

Comment: Note that $0$ is in your set! ($n = 1$) So of course, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ you can find some $a$ in the set such that $a > - \varepsilon$. Just choose $a = 0$

Comment: Thanks! it worked!

Comment: also note that each element in the set $ \in (-1,0]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is unclear whether $n$ can be negative or not, we assume that it can be.
However, if $n$ is negative, $\frac 1 n$ is negative and hence $\frac 1 n - 1 \lt -1$.
Now say that $N$ is positive. Notice if $a \gt b \gt 0$, $\frac 1 a \lt \frac 1 b$.
Since $1$ is the smallest positive odd number, $\max S$ is achieved at $N=1$, which is $0$.
Now we will show that $\max S = \sup S$.

Suppose that it is not true. Then there are some number $K$ such that $k = \sup S$. Since $K \not = \max S$, $K$ is either more or less than $\max S$.

Suppose that $K$ is less than $\max S$. Then $\max S \gt K$, causing a contradiction.

Suppose that $K$ is more that $\max S$. Then there is some number $K^*$ such that $\max S \lt K^* \lt K$. However, since $K^* \gt \max S$, $K^*$ is larger than any element in $S$, which causes a contradiction to the definition of $\sup S$.

Therefore $\sup S = \max S = 0$.